# Filter multiple values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple data frame, how do I display the customer_id of customers who bought products A and B, but didn’t buy product C, ordered by ascending customer ID.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with `groupby` with `filter`

```
out = df.groupby('customer_id').\
     filter(lambda x : pd.Series( ['A','B']).isin(x['product_n']).all() \
                        & (~x['product_n'].isin(['C']).any()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a set for `'A','B'` and check this set is a subset of the results from the groupby of `product_n`. Also check if `C` is not in `product_n`. The combination of these two will be a True or False. Then filter out only the True to get the customer ids that have purchased products `'A'` and `'B'` and not `'C'`.

Here's how I implemented it.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'cust_id':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                   'prod_nm':['A','B','A','B','C','A','A','C','D']})
print (df)
ab = {'A','B'}
dfs = df.groupby('cust_id')['prod_nm'].apply(lambda x: (('C' not in x.tolist()) & (ab.issubset(x))))
#
print (dfs.loc[dfs])
```

This will give you:

```
cust_id
1    True
```

If you are looking for a list comprehension for this so you can get these into a list, then you can do this:

```
dfx = [k for k,v in df.groupby('cust_id')['prod_nm'].apply(set).items() if ab.issubset(v) and 'C' not in v]

print (dfx)
```

The result of this will be:

```
[1]
```

For the updated DataFrame, here's the results:

```
   cust_id prod_nm
0        1       A
1        1       B
2        2       A
3        2       B
4        2       C
5        3       A
6        3       A
7        3       B
8        3       D
```

Results using dfs.iloc:

```
cust_id
1    True
3    True
Name: prod_nm, dtype: bool
```

Results using List Comprehension

```
[1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html) and [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
(df.groupby("customer_id")["product_n"].unique()
    .apply(lambda x: 'A' in x and 'B' in x and not 'C' in x))
```